# Preserve Spaces mentioned in String format

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

```
const person = {
  name: 'John',
  middle: 'S',
  last: 'Smith'
}

const format = "{​​​​​​​ name }​​​​​​​ {​​​​​​​​    ​​​​​​middle }​​​​​​​​​​​​​​ {​​​​​​​​​​​​​​ last}​​​​​​​​​​​​​";
```

The curly braces acts like a placeholder for dynamic values. i:e `{name}` will get replaced with `John`, `{middle}` with `S`.

The issue I'm facing is with preserving the spaces in between the format. i:e if there exist two spaces in the `{name}  {middle}`, then the output should be `John  S`.

I'm replacing the placeholder with actual values and joining it with the single space, but it would be static always.

```js
const person = {
  name: 'John',
  middle: 'S',
  last: 'Smith'
}

const format = "{​​​​​​​ name }​​​​​​​ {​​​​​​​​    ​​​​​​ middle }​​​​​​​​​​​​​​ {​​​​​​​​​​​​​​ last}​​​​​​​​​​​​​";

function formatStr(obj, format) {
  return format.match(/\b\w+\b/g).map((s) => person[s]).join(' ');
}

console.log(formatStr(person, format));
```

Help would be really appreciated :)

Comment: Why are the spaces **inside** the `{}`? Why not between the placeholders?

Comment: What should the **exact** result of your example in the snippet be?

Comment: Why don't you just make all the placeholder like this: `{a} {b}`? i.e., No space between braces? I think that would be easy to work with!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - This is how I'm getting the format from backend.

Comment: Why all the [zero-width spaces](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/character.jsp?a=200B) in the example?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder could you kindly tell what is a "zero-withd-space"?

Comment: @h-sifat - It's a character defined in Unicode (see the link) that represents a space that doesn't appear visually. See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `.replace` operation, matching the substrings between `{...}` with one word inside and replacing with the values from the `person` object if they exist.

```js
const person = {
  name: 'John',
  middle: 'S',
  last: 'Smith'
}

const format = "{​​​​​​​ name }​​​​​​​ {​​​​​​​​    ​​​​​​ middle }​​​​​​​​​​​​​​ {​​​​​​​​​​​​​​ last}​​​​​​​​​​​​​";

function formatStr(obj, format) {
  return format.replace(/\{[^\w{}]*(\w+)[^\w{}]*}/g, (x,y) => person[y] ?? x);
}

console.log(formatStr(person, format));
```

This will keep all spaces and other chars in between `}` and `{`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dlYsdm/1). *Details*:

- `\{` -  a `{` char
- `[^\w{}]*` - zero or more non-word chars other than `{` and `}`
- `(\w+)` - Group 1: one or more word chars
- `[^\w{}]*` - zero or more non-word chars other than `{` and `}`
- `}` - a `}` char.

Comment: Okay. So you are capturing the first word from the curly braces and replacing it with value from object. Thank you so much :)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The spaces between `}` and `{` are preserved as they are not matched.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - I must be misunderstanding the question then. I thought they wanted to keep the spaces **within** the placeholders. ...Though now I'm wondering why I thought that.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I understand the "*The issue I'm facing is with preserving the spaces in between the format.*" part as "between placeholders, the spaces should be kept".

Comment: Yeah, I think it was just a red herring.